# populate collection with each()

Tags: jquery

I am trying to populate a collection using an each. I can get the element in one string, and I can get an alert to fire on each iteration. I just cant put the two together.

Here is my list:

4/27/2011 5:42:54 PM
4/27/2011 5:43:00 PM
4/27/2011 5:46:53 PM
4/28/2011 2:10:40 PM

Here is my code.

```
if (chosenTime > 0) {
    var myDateClass = $('.exceptionDate')
    var i = 0
    $(myDateClass).each(function () {
       var myDateClassVal = myDateClass[i].GetAttributeNode(outerText);
       //this currently gives an error              
       //if I switch this to myDateClass.text();
       // it returns the list in one string
       i++
       });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside the each use `$(this).text()`. `this` is the individual item within the each.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the map function:

```
var selected = $('.exceptionDate').map(function(i, e) {
    return $(e).text();
});

alert(selected.length);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/2wYTT/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused about `.each()`.

You may want to look at the API:

http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$(myDateClass).each(function () {
       var myDateClassVal = myDateClass[i].GetAttributeNode(outerText);
       i++; // This is not needed.
       });
```

So, if you define it as `each(function(indx, elem) { })` it will help you iterate over each element, `elem`, or refer to it by index.

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely understand what you mean, but if you want an Array of the text content of each `.exceptionDate` element, you can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) with [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).

```
var array = myDateClass.map(function () {
   return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Or in a similar manner, you can use [`jQuery.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map):

```
var array = $.map(myDateClass,function (el) {
   return $(el).text();
});
```